How do I run my Intel Core i3 1005G1 Processor below its Base Frequency?
My laptop is an Asus X515JA which uses an Intel Core i3-1005G1 icelake processor (Base clock speed 1.2 Ghz, up to 3.4 Ghz turbo boost). I noticed a strange behavior on this processor when running Windows 10 operating system:
It rarely runs below its base frequency. In the 3 years I've been using this device, I've only seen it run at 400 MHz with a constant clock speed for a short period of time (another strange behavior), other than that it runs at 1.18 Ghz or 1.19 Ghz and above.
I find this inefficient, given that most of my activities are typing and browsing, which rarely require processor clock speeds above 1 Ghz. Can this processor run at frequencies below 1.18 Ghz on Windows 10? What should I do?

What is your power plan. High performance will not allow your CPU to clock down.

I usually use balance.

One possibility would be to underclock your CPU, though there are differences from model to model on whether it has any negative side effects and how sever (ranging from no effect to breaking your CPU). But in short what you would do is enter the BIOS settings and lower the voltage for your CPU. That should reduce clock speed as well.

Try to set your power plan to "maximum battery saver", run on battery and see what happens. The issue with modern OS is that you always have a lot of background processes running. Given that your processor has two cores, 4 threads, one core will almost always be active, and the other will shut down periodically. Now, usually it is more efficient to run the tasks on base clock speed, then power down, rather than taking more time to run the same task on a lower frequency. So, you'll really have to ask the OS to save as much power as possible to make it slow down some background tasks.

I have tried switching the powerplan to power saver, which seems to be the solution to save power overall. To date I haven't seen a drop in clokspeed below base frequency, but there has been a change in the processor's more efficient behavior in using turbo boost.
I took a look at the BIOS, I saw a simple blue and gray-white UI. As I explored it, there didn't seem to be any features to make electrical adjustments to the processor.

In Power Options, for your plan, Advanced, change Processor power management settings. However, don't expect a great improvement -- the CPU is continually refreshing screen, performing drive I/O, managing the TCP/IP stack, playing audio, etc.


Running your processor at 400Mhz is going to be a horrible experience by the way. Even the 1.2Ghz should be a horrible experience. You’ll immediately revert the change.

I have tried lowering the minimum processor state. I understand that this will lower the minimum frequency of the processor so that it can drop below its base clock speed. But it seems that core i3-1005g1 and perhaps others have other reasons to keep running above the base clock speed even if their minimum processor state is lowered to 5% or even 0%. Perhaps this is to prevent a horrible user experience.
